# Qt install won't copy files

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm using Qt 5.5 for a project, and am trying to use the install feature to copy files into the build directory. I have in my .pro (this is a simplified version I am using to try and figure out the issue):

```
copy_files.path = $${OUT_PWD}/debug
copy_files.files = win32_libs/*
INSTALLS += copy_files
```

I have in the build configuration an extra step after "make" which is "Make install" for both debug and release (selected from the "Make" drop down item). After clean -> run qmake -> build, Qt absolutely refuses to copy any of the files in "win32_libs" into the debug build directory.

If I specify just "win32_libs" instead of "win32_libs/*", it will copy the directory (not helpful), and it turns out it will copy any directory, but no files unless they are CONTAINED in a directory (again, not helpful).

So how can I convince it to just copy the files?

Answer (score 0):

After facing similar problem and no being able to solve it directly I decided to do the workaround for the Windows target like:

```
# post build copy dependencies
win32 {
     # all the necessary files listed relative to the root project directory
    OTHER_FILES += stuff\myfile1 stuff\myfile2
    OTHER_FILES += stuff\myfile3 stuff\myfile4

    DESTDIR_WIN = $$DESTDIR
    DESTDIR_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
    # debug pro file statement
    message(Destination WINDOWS $$DESTDIR_WIN)

    PWD_WIN = $${PWD}
    PWD_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
    for(FILE, OTHER_FILES){
        QMAKE_POST_LINK += xcopy /d/y $${PWD_WIN}\\$${FILE} $${DESTDIR_WIN}$$escape_expand(\\n\\t)
    }
}
```

And xcopy command provided with parameters to avoid actual unnecessary copy.